# vanilla python - (plagiarism checker) How to detect the words that is identical in the original sentence?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple plagiarism checker by vanilla python. without using external libs in python

So if the identical words comes successively more than 4 times, I want to print ouput(the successive identical words)

I tried the below code.
But it show every identical words even though the words does not succesively identical less than 4 times..

```py
b1='i guess that osaka city is just a souless city it is obviously weird'.split(' ')
a1='all of the meaning less time i guess thinking that osaka city is huge a souless city it is obviously weird'.split(' ')

# expected_result
#['that osaka city is','a souless city it is obviously weird']



temp1=[]
for b in b1:
    for a in a1:
        if b == a :
            temp1.append(b)

        if len(temp1)>=4:
            print(' '.join(temp1))
        else:
            print('==')
```

However the result was

```
i guess that osaka city city is is a souless city city it is is obviousl
y
i guess that osaka city city is is a souless city city it is is obviousl
y
i guess that osaka city city is is a souless city city it is is obviousl
y weird
```

And ... This is what I want to make

```py
#### Example; 

# INPUT
a = 'Hello my name is Osaka, today I learned about Mochi
is just a shit of snowman'
b = 'Hello my name is Kidney, bullshit, mann yesterday I learned about Katzu is just a shit of snowman'
# EXPECTED OUTPUT
['Hello my name is','is just a shit of snowman']
```

Answer (score 1):

You take every word in `a1` and compare it to every word in `b1`. All the matching words are added to `temp1`. But you never check the **sequences** of words. That's why you get all words of `a1` that are in `b1`.

Here's a simple idea to compare sequences: take every couple of indexes in `a1` and `b1` and try to advance while the characters match. If you found 4 or more matching characters, output the characters :

```
B='i guess that osaka city is just a souless city it is obviously weird'.split(' ')
A='all of the meaning less time i guess thinking that osaka city is huge a souless city it is obviously weird'.split(' ')

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        m, n = i, j
        while m<len(A) and n<len(B) and A[m] == B[n]:
            m, n = m+1, n+1
        if m-i >= 4:
            print((i, j), A[i:m])
```

If you admit `itertools` in "Vanilla Python" (I know VanillaJS, but I'm not sure of what "Vanilla Python" means), you can write:

```
import itertools
for i, j in itertools.product(range(len(A)), range(len(B))):
    L = [u for u,v in itertools.takewhile(lambda u_v : u_v[0]==u_v[1], zip(A[i:], B[j:]))]
    if len(L)>=4:
        print((i,j), L)
```

Output

```
(9, 2) ['that', 'osaka', 'city', 'is']
(14, 7) ['a', 'souless', 'city', 'it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']
(15, 8) ['souless', 'city', 'it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']
(16, 9) ['city', 'it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']
(17, 10) ['it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']
```

You get some garbage since if `['a', 'souless', 'city', 'it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']` is the longest match starting at `(14, 7)`, we know that the list starting at `(15, 8)` will be a match too. Let's add an `exclude` set to remove those sublists:

```
exclude = set()
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        if (i,j) in exclude:
            exclude.remove((i,j))
            continue
        m, n = i, j
        while m<len(A) and n<len(B) and A[m] == B[n]:
            m, n = m+1, n+1
        if m-i >= 4:
            print((i, j), A[i:m])
            exclude.update((i+k, j+k) for k in range(1, m-i))
            print ("exclude = ", exclude)
```

Output:

```
(9, 2) ['that', 'osaka', 'city', 'is']
exclude =  {(12, 5), (11, 4), (10, 3)}
(14, 7) ['a', 'souless', 'city', 'it', 'is', 'obviously', 'weird']
exclude =  {(20, 13), (16, 9), (17, 10), (15, 8), (19, 12), (18, 11)}
```

This mehod works, but it's very slow: the time complexity is O(|A|*|B|*longest match). It's possible to spare some checks with the following method: build, for the list |B|, a dictionary `word -> [positions]` to avoid rechecking all indexes in `B` for each word of `A`:

```
positions_by_word_in_B = {}
for j, word in enumerate(B):
    positions_by_word_in_B.setdefault(word, []).append(j)
```

Output:

```
{'i': [0], 'guess': [1], 'that': [2], 'osaka': [3], 'city': [4, 9], 'is': [5, 11], 'just': [6], 'a': [7], 'souless': [8], 'it': [10], 'obviously': [12], 'weird'
: [13]}
```

The main loop becomes:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in positions_by_word_in_B.get(A[i], []):
        # all positions of A[i] in B, maybe none
```

The time complexity falls to O(|B| + |A|*|max occurences of a word of A in B|*longest match). You can also stop the iteration at len(A)-4 instead of len(A)-1.

If you want to check for plagiarism against a big set of documents, this will probably still be too slow.